# How to understand `std::make_shared<Object>("foo")`?

Tags: c++, template-classes

What does `std::make_shared<Object>("foo")` do?

```
std::shared_ptr<Object> p1 = std::make_shared<Object>("foo");
```

I know that `std::make_shared<T>` is template class and I could understand `Object("foo")` is a temporary object indeed. But I could not understand `std::make_shared<Object>("foo")`.

Can someone explain me, step by step, sequence of objects created and operations done by it?

Comment: `std::make_shared<T>()` is not a template class.   It is a helper function that (1) dynamically allocates a `T` that is initialised (constructed) using the supplied arguments (any arguments - of which there may be zero or more - between the `()`) and (2) constructs and returns a `std::shared_ptr<T>` to manage that object.

Comment: Isn't `std::make_shared<T>()` a template function?

Comment: Yes, it is a template function.   You describe it as a templated class, which it is not.

Comment: I see, i am sorry for disturbing you.I would do my best to avoid it.

Comment: @john I think your comments are helpful.Did you delete them just now?Or just because we have simmilar names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
std::make_shared<Object>("foo")
```

## method

Notice the **std::make_shared** at the start of this code. It identifies a function. If we put the actual function aside and step back a little, then before the <> signs and the () sign you have a function name.

## generic

The  in this code specifies that the generic T is specified in this case to be Object. It's not a good idea to think of it as if it was a temporary object. It's a specification.

## the call

**("foo")** is ensuring that the function is called and a parameter is passed to it.

## bottom line

The [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared) is providing you a proper description of this:

[image]

It tells you that the constructor of the given type specified (Object in this case) will be instantiated and will be wrapped in a [shared_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr).

Comment: I would follow your advice. As you say:"The in this code specifies that the generic T is specified in this case to be Object. It's not a good idea to think of it as if it was a temporary object. It's a specification.", one more question raises: **what "It's a specification."** mean?

Comment: @John it basically means that in terms of generics used here, ```<T>``` means "some type", which in general is used to make sure that you can reuse the same code in different use-cases. Here, in particular, you might want to create a shared_ptr of Object now, but later you may use a different type. At the time of the implementation of ```make_shared``` the people implementing it could not tell in advance that you will need a shared_ptr of Object. They were agnostic about it and decided to support any type. This is the basic idea behind generics.

Comment: @John And here, the ```<Object>``` part is specifying that ```T``` is ```Object``` in this case. It's nice that the funciton itself uses a generic type and supports any types, but, in your particular case the type is known and is to be specified.

Comment: I see.Thank you for the clarification.I agree with @Remy Lebeau that `std::make_shared<T>` is a template function.But Peter says that it is a helper function.What do you think of it? Thanks a lot .

Comment: @John it's both. It's a template function, because it's using the generic of ```<T>``` as a template. It's also a helper function because if performs part of the computation of your function.

Answer (score 3):

`std::make_shared` is a template function, not a template class.

The function's template parameter specifies the type to be created.

The function's parameters are passed as-is to that type's constructor.

The function returns a `std::shared_ptr` that holds a pointer to the type created.

So, `std::make_shared<Object>("foo")` dynamically creates an `Object` instance constructed with `"foo"`, and returns a `std::shared_ptr<Object>` holding a pointer to that instance.

This is equivalent to the following (but not quite the same, as there are additional optimizations involved behind the scenes):

```
std::shared_ptr<Object> p1(new Object("foo"));
```

Comment: Could me tell me where i can find the related source code?

Comment: Start in the header file `<memory>` although the code may or may not be located in that file.

Comment: @john Btw,isn't `std::make_shared<T>()` a template function?Peter says that it is a helper function.I am confused.

Comment: It is both a template function and a helper function. Helper function is not an official C++ term.